# Is this a good way to manage Disposable objects in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, idisposable

I am overriding the `Controller.Dispose(bool)` method in my ASP.NET MVC2 Controllers in order to dispose of things as needed, while leaving them alive for as long as possible. This is as opposed to disposing of them prior to returning from the Controller's action method.

My question, in short; does this work as I expect?

From what I'm seeing so far, this seems to provide exactly what I need; all `IDisposable` objects are getting disposed (The `Controller.Dispose()` method calls the virtual `Controller.Dispose(bool)`), but not until they are no longer needed.

---

EDIT #2:

I appreciate the advice on what I should be doing. I mean that; I up-voted just such an answer, in fact.

For the purposes of this question, though, let's assume that I have evaluated my own needs and have decided that calling an occasional related-entity-property in my View works best for *me*, and that I have decided that I am not really in need of a Dependency Injection framework just to make sure my objects are disposed of properly.

What I really just need to know for right now is if anyone is aware of lifetime-related issues to disposing of these objects in an overridden `Controller.Dispose(bool)` method.

Comment: Your View shouldn't run extra queries. :)

Comment: It's not running extra queries explicitly; it's almost always some related entity class member that I end up calling into based on View-centric information. I know that information can be pre-loaded via EF or L2S, but I do not always know what will be needed in time, and sometimes they are only needed for certain rows. One thing I like about the EF/L2S stuff is that I can conditionally display those things without what looks/feels like a 'query'. Yes - I know a query is actually happening. But it's a value judgment I've made for my applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

+1 and thanks for this question.  I can't give you an answer based on my own experience, but I did find [this post](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/08/20/asp-net-mvc-tip-34-dispose-of-your-datacontext-or-don-t.aspx) by Stephen Walter describing exactly your situation (I believe), and a [comment](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/08/20/asp-net-mvc-tip-34-dispose-of-your-datacontext-or-don-t.aspx#599) by [@Craig Stuntz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7714/craig-stuntz) suggesting the same pattern you describe.  Sounds like you are good here :)

Answer (score 5):

Take a look into inversion of control and dependency injection. The frameworks out there (Structure Map, Ninject, Autofac, Unity etc.) will take care of disposing objects for you depending on the scope you assigned to that object (ex: per request scope will dispose of objects at the end of a request)

Comment: +1 I'm upvoting this because it's a good answer and could be helpful to many who find this question via search engine. It's not exactly the answer I'm looking for, though; I just want to know if there's anything I'm not thinking of regarding the lifetime of those objects when I dispose of them with the controller.